# Prevent other users from geting a file in TFS 2010?

Tags: tfs

Is ther a way in TFS 2010 to prevent other users from perfroming a get on a config file that is only to be avaliable for the build process?
Each user is supposed to have their own versions of the files on theier own workstations.

BR

Johan

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. you can get each developer to "cloak" the file in their workspace.

   - Open Source control Explorer and select the "WorkSpace" dropdown
   - Select "WorkSpaces"
   - Click on the Edit button
   - in the "Working Folders" area at the bottom of the screen add a new row, The Status should be "Cloaked" and the "Source Control Folder" should point to the folder or file you want to ignore (you can only navigate to a folder in the "Wizard" but you can add a file manually)
2. Using Security permissions

   - Navigate to the file in source control explorer
   - Right click on the file and select "Properties"
   - Select the "Security" Tab
   - Uncheck the "Inherit Security settings" check box
   - Remove the Group that contains your developers (Unsually the [Team Project]\Contributors group)

The downsides to these approaches
1. The Devs will have to do this on each machine \ workspace they are using. 
2. The devs may accidently try to check in the file, this will cause an error.

If you do both then you'll mitigate the problem with the devs checking the file in accidently as it will be cloaked, but you'll still have the issue of each developer needing to set up the cloaked file in every workspace.

Alternatively you could have a "special" version of the file checked in to a different location in source control ,which is copied in to the correct location (overwriting whatever the devs have checked in), as part of your build process.

Answer (score 0):

you can give rights 
from source code security tab.
u have to add the person or group in Global Groups And after that you can give any rights from security tab!